# How do TorCoins work?

Tags: altcoin

The tor network relies on volunteers providing bandwidth. This is a limiting factor of that system, since there is currently no direct benefit by operating a tor relay.

As I understood, TorCoins are altcoins that can be mined by providing bandwidth to the system. But how would a Proof-of-Work mechanism work for such a system?

Comment: I know nothing of TorCoin, but reading your question it sounds that it doesn't use PoW at all, but some Proof-of-Bandwidth. How they do that without it being gameable, I have no idea.

Comment: I try to understand [this paper](http://www.robgjansen.com/publications/torpath-hotpets2014.pdf). The difference between PoW and PoB (Proof-of-Bandwith) is that there is more than one entity needed to bring that Proof. Thats my limited understanding of the concept so far.

Answer (score 1):

TorCoin
is an alternative cryptocurrency, or altcoin, based on the Bitcoin
protocol [8]. Unlike Bitcoin, its proof-of-work scheme is based on bandwidth
rather than computation. To \mine" a TorCoin, a relay transfers bandwidth
over the Tor network. Since relays can sell TorCoin on any existing altcoin
exchange, TorCoin e ectively compensates them for contributing bandwidth
to the network, and does not require clients to pay for access to it.

For more info, see the [white paper on TorCoin](https://petsymposium.org/2014/papers/Ghosh.pdf).